# Update existing Lens on a Dashboard in Analytics Cloud

Tags: analytics-cloud

How do I update an existing Lens on a Dashboard in Analytics Cloud. (ie. If I want to add a filter to that lens).

So far I can only do this by:

Unable to edit existing lens.

Instead
- open Lens in edit mode of Dashboard editor clicking "Open as Lens" icon in top right.
- Make amendments
- Clip new lens to designer
- Create new Widget, using similar properties to existing widget.
- delete existing widget.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems there is no easy / direct way..

if you are comfortable with JSON, you can edit / manipulate the Dashboard / Lens JSON directly to apply the changes.

If you go to https://{YourInstance}/insights/web/lens.apexp , you will get the JSON Viewer for all your dashboards & lenses where you can edit it directly.

here's a detailed reference for [Analytics Cloud JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_modify.htm) which has details on how to view/modify them.

and I believe its in their roadmap to enhance the Dataset & Dashboard editor to support all these functions.

Comment: Perfect! Changing the Alias reference on the Lens does the job.